# Stop Magento from emptying the shopping cart before payment confirmation?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

This is one of the most vital problems I have found since I started testing Magento for my web store. It's kind of a no-brainer that it's absolutely unnecessary and harmful to sales to empty cart **before payment confirmation**, which unfortunately, Magento does.

If the user selects PayPal (website standard) for payment method and for some reason clicks "Back to xxxx" (your business name at PayPal) on the PayPal payment page **without paying**, PayPal would redirect the user back to http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/, which now is an EMPTY cart.

I think it should be after payment confirmation / PayPal IPN that the cart be empty-ed, instead of any point before that.

Even if the user wants to continue again, he or she'd be annoyed from searching and adding all the products again and would very probably just leave.

Any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: Hey, can you please confirm which of the below solution worked for you Since it will help others like me to test and get the workaround. Thanks

Comment: @echoashu, tried all of them but nothing worked for me.

Comment: @echoashu, for me also did not work. I am using onepage checkout.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

File: `~/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

Replace this:

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
/**
 * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
 * we will save the order in return action.
 */
if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
    $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
}
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

With this one:

```
/**
 * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
 * we will save the order in return action.
 */
if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
    $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setIsActive(1) ;
}
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

Comment: Core files should not be changed. You should always override controller.

Comment: I am using IWD onepage checkout. this code not worked for me. plz tell how to do taht?

Comment: Please check once http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130941/cart-becomes-empty-when-cancel-the-transaction-in-onestep-checkout

Comment: This solution is creating the order before trying the payment. But if you cancel several times and then go to MyAccount/MyOrders you'll see all the tries, all the orders. I just want to keep the quote but not the orders. Didn't work for me...

Answer (score 4):

For Paypal I found the cancel action inside the app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/StandardController.php cancelAction

I changed the code like that for cancel action

```
public function cancelAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $session->setQuoteId($session->getPaypalStandardQuoteId(true));
    if ($session->getLastRealOrderId()) {
        $incrementId = $session->getLastRealOrderId();
        if (empty($incrementId)) {
            $session->addError($this->__('Your payment failed, Please try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($session->getLastRealOrderId());
        $session->getQuote()->setIsActive(false)->save();
        $session->clear();
        try {
            $order->setActionFlag(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ACTION_FLAG_CANCEL, true);
            $order->cancel()->save();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $session->addError($this->__($e->getMessage()));
                Mage::logException($e);
                continue;
            }
        }
        $cart->save();
        $session->addError($this->__('Your payment failed. Please try again later'));
    }
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

It worked pretty good for me and there is no need to change any other place for that.

It marks the current order as Cancelled and restores the cart with using that order and redirects the user to cart again.

Answer (score 0):

/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php this file is the actual controller file, but depends up on the payment method extensions it will change with Namespace/Modulename/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

Find function saveOrderAction()

find these lines

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
        /**
         * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
         * we will save the order in return action.
         */
        if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

comment this line `//$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();`
and add below codes inside the if condition so the condition will look like ..

```
//$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
        if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
                    $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
                    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setIsActive(1) ;
                }
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
       $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

This is i have done with the third party Payment extension.

Answer (score -1):

Since Magento version 1.6.0.0 (juli 2011) you can enable **"Persistent Shopping Cart"**

under

```
System > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart
```

This should solve this problem.

Use these settings to make it work

```
Enable Persistence = Yes
Persistence Lifetime (seconds) = 31536000
Enable "Remember Me" = Yes
"Remember Me" Default Value = Yes
Clear Persistence on Log Out = No
Persist Shopping Cart = Yes
```

Good luck :)

Comment: But isnt this cart also emptied on checkout? (click PAY and go to PSP page)

Answer (score -2):

Your issue is with the way `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveOrderAction()` behaves.

More specific: open `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

```
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();//this makes the cart empty (sets the quote as converted to order)
    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
        $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

You can replace the last part:

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();//....
```

with:

```
if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
    $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setIsActive(1) ;
}
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

Comment: on what file is this?

Comment: @AryehArmon, i have inserted the path for this file. Check once.